# Can't connect to a testcontainer Neo4J instance?

Tags: docker, kotlin, neo4j, junit5, testcontainers

this is my test class:

```
@Testcontainers
@ReactiveDataNeo4jTest
internal class RepositoryIT {

    @Container
    private val container = KNeo4jContainer.instance

    @Test
    fun `should answer with One`() {
        val boltUrl = container.getBoltUrl()
        GraphDatabase.driver(
                boltUrl,
                AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "123456"))
                .use { driver ->
                    driver.session().use { session ->
                        val res = session.run("OPTIONAL MATCH(n) RETURN 1 AS value")
                        val one = res.single().get("value").asInt()
                        assertThat(one).isEqualTo(2)
                    }
                }

    }

}

object KNeo4jContainer {

    val instance by lazy {
        startNeo4jContainer()
    }

    private fun startNeo4jContainer(): Neo4jContainer<*> =
            Neo4jContainer<Nothing>("neo4j:4.1.0").apply {
                withEnv("NEO4J_AUTH", "neo4j/123456")
                withExposedPorts(7687)
                withExposedPorts(7473)
                withExposedPorts(7474)
                start()
            }
}
```

When I check with `docker ps -a` it seems to have started

```
  CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                                                       NAMES                                                     
 -------------- ----------------------------------- ------------------------ -------------------- ------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------- 
  102b11fa5c7c   neo4j:4.1.0                         "/sbin/tini -g -- /d…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:32791->7473/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32790->7474/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32789->7687/tcp   pensive_williams                                          
  92fac72190e0   testcontainersofficial/ryuk:0.3.0   "/app"                   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:32788->8080/tcp                                                     testcontainers-ryuk-ecc3bfaf-44ba-482d-ae5f-ddba9a70182f
```

but I cant connect to it:

> org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Unable to
> connect to localhost:7687, ensure the database is running and that
> there is a working network connection to it.

I can run the test against a container started with the same  configuration via `docker-compose up`:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  neo4j:
    image:  neo4j:4.1.0
    ports:
      # Http
      - "7474:7474"
      # Https
      - "7473:7473"
      # Bolt
      - "7687:7687"
    environment:
      # initial password reset
      "NEO4J_AUTH": "neo4j/secret"
```

but I thought that would only be for not having to start a new container while developing tests.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

Changed AuthTokens to AuthTokens.none() after setting admin passwort null in the start-up code - still no success.

**Edit**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <!-- groupId, artifactId, version, name and description ommitted -->
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.72</kotlin.version>
        <neo4j.test.port>7687</neo4j.test.port>
        <neo4j.test.auth>neo4j/secret</neo4j.test.auth>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-kotlin-extensions</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-reactor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rx-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency><dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rx-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rx-spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.neo4j.test</groupId>
                    <artifactId>neo4j-harness</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.33.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <name>neo4j:4.1.0</name>
                            <alias>neo4j</alias>
                            <run>
                                <env>
                                    <NEO4J_AUTH>${neo4j.test.auth}</NEO4J_AUTH>
                                </env>
                                <ports>
                                    <port>${neo4j.test.port}:3306</port>
                                </ports>
                                <wait>
                                    <!-- time based waiting is the only option, because TCP-based or log-based polling are not reliable.
                                   see https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin/issues/328
                                   Alternatively we can wait log- or tcp-based and try to connect for a while in the test code -->
                                    <time>8000</time>
                                </wait>
                            </run>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*IT.*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <neo4j.port>${neo4j.test.port}</neo4j.port>
                        <neo4j.auth>${neo4j.test.auth}</neo4j.auth>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*IT.*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Solution**

```
 private fun startNeo4jContainer(): Neo4jContainer<*> {
        val container = Neo4jContainer<Nothing>("neo4j:4.1.0").apply {
            withAdminPassword(null)
            start()
        }
        return container
    }
```

Comment: Are you running Docker on a Windows machine?

Comment: I am running it on Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa

Comment: I finally got it. Thanks to @NeoAnderson I took a close look at the ports. But the important bit was to realize, that I pass the driver the random URL from testcontainersofficial/ryuk:0.3.0 via `container.getBoltUrl()`, so I probably should _not_ expose the ports on localhost, at least for the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works a little bit differently as per https://www.testcontainers.org/features/networking/

> From the host's perspective Testcontainers actually exposes this on a
> random free port. This is by design, to avoid port collisions that may
> arise with locally running software or in between parallel test runs.

And the bottom part of https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/

> Now, in your test code (or a suitable setup method), you can obtain
> details necessary to connect to this database:
>
> - `mysql.getJdbcUrl()` provides a JDBC URL your code can connect to
> - `mysql.getUsername()` provides the username your code should pass to the driver
> - `mysql.getPassword()` provides the password your code should pass to the driver

Comment: Thank you, but I'm already getting the url from the container: `container.getBoltUrl()`. Also I am using the [Neo4J-Module](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/neo4j/), not the MySql-Module.

Comment: If it's still relevant and you can include a pom/build.gradle I could try that out.

Comment: Shure, it's a side-project. It has time. Added a pom for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `Neo4jContainer#withAdminPassword` for setting the password instead of setting the environment variable.

Otherwise, it will be overridden here:
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/6bdbc8ffe257fc879791eb7fddcf3b5ecccdd52d/modules/neo4j/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/Neo4jContainer.java#L118

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in Windows, default 0.0.0.0 address isn't translated to localhost.

I cannot reproduce, but adding these environment variables should do the job:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  neo4j:
    image:  neo4j:4.1.0
    ports:
      # Http
      - "7474:7474"
      # Https
      - "7473:7473"
      # Bolt
      - "7687:7687"
    environment:
      # initial password reset
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/secret
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_advertised__address=localhost:7473
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_advertised__address=localhost:7474
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address=localhost:7687
```

Comment: Hello @bsideup. Is there something I can improve about my answer, or am I obviously wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I'm running this on a Linux machine. When I start the container via the docker-compose file, the tests already pass. I might be wrong, but I thought, that I should be able to start the container via the test class only?