# Testcontainers: execute TC_INITSCRIPT at each test

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, testcontainers, quarkus-panache

In a quakus project, I successfully set up testcontainers using only the following configuration:

```
%test.quarkus.datasource.driver=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
%test.quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
%test.quarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:postgresql:11:///dbname?TC_INITSCRIPT=file:my-file.sql
```

This is amazing how easy it is.

However, as I test the deletion of entities, I'd like to execute the initscript before each test, i.a. start each test with the initial DB.

Any idea how to achieve it?

I also tested by creating the PostgreSQLContainer from the test class in order to manage its lifecycle as I need. The problem is that the container port value is random, I need to set it in quarkus configuration but it doesn't work (it seems to be too late: "Connection to 127.0.0.1:6432 refused"). I did it this way:

```
@Testcontainers
@QuarkusTest
class MyTest {

  class MyPostgreSQLContainer(imageName: String) : PostgreSQLContainer<MyPostgreSQLContainer>(imageName)

  companion object {

    @Container
    val postgres = MyPostgreSQLContainer("postgres:11")
      .withDatabaseName("integtest")
      .withUsername("postgres")
      .withPassword("pwd")
      .withExposedPorts(5432)

    @BeforeAll
    @JvmStatic
    internal fun beforeAll() {

      postgres.start()
      System.setProperty("QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_JDBC_URL", "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:${postgres.firstMappedPort}/kpi_integtest");
      println("BeforeAll init() method called")
    }

  }
```

with the application.properties config:

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:6432/integtest
```

Comment: Why don't you set env property to getJdbcUrl() instead of **firstMappedPort**?
Also check out this comment
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63498933/8587732
If that doesn't help - I'm happy to chat more :)

Comment: @VitalyChura I tried with jdbcUrl also but it dosn't work neither. The `System.setProperty("QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_JDBC_URL"` has no effect, I think that quarkus has already started and doesn"t watch for env variables change.

Comment: Can you share project example?